# Is getGeneratedKeys() supposed to return values 1 to n over all INSERT operations?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Suppose you have some code like this making use of JDBCs getGeneratedKeys() method:

```
private static void writeToDB(String url[], String project[]){

    try{
        //Update main table
        String sql = "INSERT INTO main (url, project) VALUES(?,?)";
        PreparedStatement mainStmt = dbConn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        for(int i = 0; i < url.length; i++){
            mainStmt.setString(1, url[i]);
            mainStmt.setString(2, project[i]);
            mainStmt.executeUpdate();
        }

        ResultSet projectId = mainStmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        projectId.next();
        int projectID = projectId.getInt(1);
        System.out.println("AutoGeneratedKey: " + projectID);

        mainStmt.close();
        projectId.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Now there is a bunch of entries in your database prior to executing the above INSERT command.
The table would look roughly like this:

### ID |  url            | project

1  |google.com       |A
2  |bing.com         |B

with the ID as the primary key and on autoincrement.

I would expect getGeneratedKeys() to return the value 3,4,...,n for the INSERT command above, but instead I get 1,2,...,n.

Since I want to use the IDs as foreign keys in other tables getGeneratedKeys() does not provide the correct values (the acutal IDs), but always starts counting at 1, despite prior entries to the database.

**How do you get the actually created ID?** I didn't see any other thread related to this method reporting to have the same problem.

Comment: What did the table look like after the insert?

Comment: New entries where added with correctly incremented IDs (3,4,...,n) and urls and projects according to the arrays. I wrote this example out of my head. The "problem" I described in my post above acutally occurred in a program with 500+ lines of code + a database with a bunch of tables, but I didn't want to spam lots of unnecessary code. Is getGeneratedKeys() supposed to return the actual ID values or does the method always starts with one?

Comment: It's supposed to return the actual generated keys, and it does for me. Sounds like something else went wrong. Maybe the code used the row indexes instead of the values?

Comment: I agree with @EJP, there is something else wrong with your actual code. I just pasted your sample code into Eclipse and I got `AutoGeneratedKey: 4` after adding two new rows to a table that already contained two rows, so your sample code works correctly (at least to the extent that it returns the generated ID from the *last* INSERT performed by the loop).

Comment: I truncated my actual database and ran my code a couple of times with the correct keys returned now. I guess the mistake is/was somewhere within the stored data. I will keep an eye out for the problem to occure again with new data added for the next couple of days. If the problem is still gone then, I will consider this fixed. Thanks for checking the code and your replies. (I will edit this post in the next couple of days)